# R create unique combinations of IDs in a given class (all combinations not getting created)

Tags: r, data-manipulation

Hi I have a dataset like the following:

```r
library(gtools)

z <- c(120, 122, 124, 126)
ID <- as.character(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12))
IQ <- c(120.5, 123, 125, 122.5, 122.1, 121.7, 123.2, 123.7, 120.7, 122.3, 120.1, 122)
Section <- c("A", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "B", "A", "B", "A", "B", "B")
zz <- data.frame(ID, IQ, Section)
```

I am trying to create **unique combinations** of the `ID`s if the `ID`'s lie in the given classes: 120-122, 122-124 and 124-126.

```r
combin_list <- list("list",length(z))
Initial_IQ <- 0
jj <- 1

for (IQ1 in z) {
  obs_list <- zz[(zz$IQ < IQ1 & zz$IQ >= Initial_IQ), ] 

  ### Edit - Include the lower bound and exclude the upper bound in the above row

  print("############")
  print(IQ1)
  print(obs_list)
  print("############")
    
  if (nrow(obs_list) > 2) {
    combination_list <- as.data.frame(combinations(n = nrow(obs_list), r = 2, v = obs_list$ID, repeats.allowed = F))
    combination_list$V1 <-  as.character(combination_list$V1) #without this some error creeps up
    combination_list$V2 <- as.character(combination_list$V2)
    combination_list <- combination_list[combination_list$V1 != combination_list$V2, ]
    combination_list <- cbind(combination_list, Previous_IQ_class = Initial_IQ, Next_class = IQ1)

    print(combination_list)
    print("############")
    combin_list[[jj]] <- combination_list
    Initial_IQ <- IQ1
    jj <- jj+1
  }
  else {
    Initial_IQ <- IQ1
    jj <- jj+1
  }
}
```

The output I am getting is weird for some classes. For instance in the class 120-122, I expect to get all the unique combinations for IDs 1,6,9 and 11. However, the combinations I am getting includes player 3 and I also do not get all the combinations for ID 11. Here's the output I get right now. The first part of the image (before the `#######`) represents the subset of the data for the class 120-122. The part after `########` represents the combinations of the ID's. The subset operation looks correct. However, in the combination operation, some error creeps in which I cannot put my finger on.

[image]

This is what I expect to get for the class 120-122:

[image]

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong? Is there a better way to do this in R? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what if you have 122? or 124? can you define how to group the ones on the boundary?

Comment: @Onyambu In each class, include the lower bounds and exclude the upper bounds. For example in the class 120-122, include observations with 120 and exclude 122 IQs. I also edited the code. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: do you prefer any packages or Base R is perfect for you?

Comment: I would eventually need to do this operation for around 16 million different rows of z. There could be different IQ classes (for eg of class size 2, 3, 4 etc.). In that case, I whichever is the faster method. But for now it would be helpful to see a working solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)
zz%>%
 mutate(ID=as.character(ID),vec=as.character(cut(IQ,c(120,122,124,126),right=F)))%>%
      group_by(vec)%>%
      summarize(if(n()>1)list(data.frame(t(combn(ID,2)),stringsAsFactors = F))
                else list(data.frame(X1=ID,X2=ID,stringsAsFactors = F)))%>%
      unnest()%>%
      bind_cols(read.csv(text=gsub("[^0-9,]","",.$vec),h=F))
# A tibble: 28 x 5
   vec       X1    X2       V1    V2
   <chr>     <chr> <chr> <int> <int>
 1 [120,122) 1     6       120   122
 2 [120,122) 1     9       120   122
 3 [120,122) 1     11      120   122
 4 [120,122) 6     9       120   122
 5 [120,122) 6     11      120   122
 6 [120,122) 9     11      120   122
 7 [122,124) 2     4       122   124
 8 [122,124) 2     5       122   124
 9 [122,124) 2     7       122   124
10 [122,124) 2     8       122   124
# ... with 18 more rows
```

Comment: Can you explain what's going on? The code is pretty dense

Comment: Haven't seen you for a while.  How are you

Comment: @akrun things are not that great trying my best. hope all is well for you too.

Comment: Keep doing your best.  I am sure that things will work for you.

Comment: @Onyambu Thanks for your help. I have a follow up question (which is an extension of the above question). In addition to the above, suppose I also wanted to segregate the individuals by Section, i.e. only allow people in Section A to match with those in Section A. What would I need to change in that case?

Comment: @Onyambu also could you explain what this line is doing: "bind_cols(read.csv(text=gsub("[^0-9,]","",.$vec),h=F))"? Specifically the read.csv portion. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Prometheus first `gsub("[^0-9,]","",.$vec)` deletes the `[` and `)` that you see in the `vec` column. then you separate this into two columns using the `read.csv` function. ie reading this vector as a dataframe. then you bind it to the original table