# R unique combinations from given ranges quickly and using less system resource

Tags: r, tidyverse

This is a follow up question from here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55912086/3988575

I have a dataset like this:

```
ID=as.character(c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))
IQ=c(120.5,128.1,126.5,122.5,127.1,129.7,124.2,123.7,121.7,122.3,120.9,122.4,125.7,126.4,128.2,129.1,121.2,128.4,127.6,125.1)
Section=c("A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B","A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A")
zz=data.frame(ID,IQ,Section)
zz_new=do.call("rbind", replicate(zz, n=30, simplify = FALSE))
```

What I would like to do is to match people by the range of their IQ (which was the previous question).

Now, I want to create multiple levels of the ranges. For example one range can be 10 IQ classes: 120-121,121-122,122-123....129-130. Another example is a single IQ class:120-130. All the possible combinations of the above can be obtained by:

```
IQ_Class=c(120,121,122,123,124,125,126,127,128,129,130)
n = length(IQ_Class)-2
all_combin=expand.grid(replicate(n, 0:1, simplify = FALSE))
all_combin$First=1
all_combin$Last=1
all_combin_new=all_combin[c("First",names(all_combin)[1:(length(names(all_combin))-2)],"Last")] #Reorder columns
all_combin_new = t((apply(all_combin_new,1,function(x)(x*IQ_Class)))) #Multiply by IQ classes
all_combin_new = apply(all_combin_new, 1, function(x) { x[x!=0] })
```

Note that the final object all_combin_new provides a list of lists of all the classes (a total of 512 classes in total).

**Now what I want to do is to take one class (one element from all_combin_new) and create all the combinations of ID's in that particular IQ class by their section. Save this dataset and take the next class from all_combin_new and repeat the operation.**

From the previous answer, I was able to to modify the code to consider the combinations by Section by changing the following in the previous question:

```
zz1=list("list",length(all_combin_new))
for (i in 1:length(all_combin_new)){ #changed this line to run for all combinations in all_combin_new
  zz2=all_combin_new[[i]]
  zz11=zz_new%>%
    mutate(ID=as.character(ID),vec=as.character(cut(IQ,zz2,right=F)))%>%
    group_by(vec,Section)%>% #Changed this line
    summarize(if(n()>1)list(data.frame(t(combn(ID,2)),stringsAsFactors = F))
              else list(data.frame(X1=ID,X2=ID,stringsAsFactors = F)))%>%
    unnest()%>%
    bind_cols(read.csv(text=gsub("[^0-9,]","",.$vec),h=F))
  zz1[[i]]=as.data.frame(zz11)
}
```

**My actual dataset has about 10K (as compared to zz_new here) observations with 20 Sections (leading to 2^18=262144 ranges of IQ as compared to the the length of all_combin_new list here = 512).** This causes two main issues:

a) Time: The speed is extremely slow. Is there a way to increase the speed?

b) Size of objects created: In my tests, even without considering as high number of combinations, the lists grow too big and the code fails. What alternate approaches could I use here? Note that in the list of list that I obtain here, I also need to do further computations.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

P.S.Please let me know if any part is unclear or any part of the code has some inadvertent errors.

Comment: Another approach instead of looping through all combinations would be to figure out each range. 120 - 121 only needs to be done once but because of the combinations, it's done 256 times. Then you would recreate whichever IQ combo that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** Now with loop to go through all IQ combos and to include `Section` as a key on join.

I used the sample data in the linked question. Instead of making a list and looping, this does everything at once.

Note there is a cartesian product, so it may still run into memory issues. If you're having trouble, you can always try data.table as you can have non-equi joins.

```
library(tidyverse)

zz <- tibble(ID=1:12
                 ,IQ=c(120.5,123,125,122.5,122.1,121.7,123.2,123.7,120.7,122.3,120.1,122)
                 ,Section=c("A","A","B","B","A","B","B","A","B","A","B","B")
)

IQ_Class <- c(120,122,124,126)

IQ_Classes <- data.frame(First = 1
             ,expand.grid(replicate(length(IQ_Class)-2, 0:1, simplify = FALSE))
             ,Last = 1)

IQ_Classes <- IQ_Classes * IQ_Class[col(IQ_Classes)]                    

IQ_Classes_List <- apply(IQ_Classes, 1, function(x) { x[x!=0] })

all_combos <- lapply(IQ_Classes_List
                     , function(IQs) 
                       {
                       z_cut <- zz%>%
                         mutate(cut_range = cut(IQ, IQ_Class, right = F, labels = F))

                       inner_join(z_cut
                                  , z_cut %>%
                                    select(V2 = ID, cut_range, Section)
                                  , by = c('cut_range', 'Section'))%>%
                         filter(V2 > ID) %>%
                         mutate(Previous_IQ_class = IQs[cut_range],
                                Next_Class = IQs[cut_range+1])
                       }
                     )%>%
  bind_rows(.id = 'IQ_List')
```

Comment: From what I understand, the above code uses one single vector of IQ_Class. Would I be able to include a case when IQ_Class is a list of list in the above code without using a for loop? Suppose that IQ_Class = list(c(120,122,124,126),c(121,123,125)), how would I incorporate that in your solution without using loops? Thanks for your answer.

Comment: From what I see, the groupings are not based on the Sections of the ID's as well. Could you please double check the output? Thanks.

Comment: You would have to loop through that. You would wrap a loop around my answer and access the ```cut``` with ```IQ_Class[i]```.

Comment: The sections need to match, too? That was unclear for me from the linked example. Add section to the inner_join by condition.

Comment: Yup. Although the Section part was mentioned in this question and not the previous one. Thanks. I will make the changes.

Comment: I edited it to include a loop via ```lapply```. Also look into ```findInterval()``` as the documentation indicates it's faster than ```cut()```. Both may fail if the IQ is outside of the range of IQ_Class so that's something to consider. As this is a cartesian product, I have no idea how well it will scale to your actual data.